# What's the main advantage to save the results in cakephp cache (i.e. tmp/cache)

Tags: cakephp, caching

I've seen so many plugins which are using Cache to store the results like results from a third part api, and directly taking the 
results from the cache instead of sending request to the third party servers again.

1.) But what is the case if the results coming from the server changes from time to time.

2.) Suppose let us assume that we're saving the no.of login attempts made by user into the cache and we'll check this count 
for securing the user's account. i.e. if user made 5 wrong login attempts then his/her account will be locked for 5mins and allow 
the user to login only after 5mins.

There may be a situation can be happen like this:

Now user has made 3 login attempts from one machine and count will be saved into the cache (cache name will be as `username`) . 
rest 2 login attempts he made from another system and count become 5 then it'll show a message that "you've done 5 incorrect login 
attempts, please try after 5mins."

Instead i can use session here to get the best results.

In that case what's the importance of Cache here ?

please tell me, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't cache results if you rely on changes. There are different APIs, some APIS send an expiration date with the result that can be used to cache the result. Sometimes you simply don't need to get new data with every request, then you cache it. Geolocation is a good example here that can be cached nearly forever.

2) This doesn't make any sense, you can't use session if you try the access an account from multiple devices. Each device will get a new session id. But in this case I would not use a cache engine at all but write it to the users table, the table needs to be queried in any case to get the login data. So it's just a write more for each attempt.

Comment: Writing to a table and caching is same here? I'm just saying session is better instead of caching the results in case of incorrect
login attempts (when making attempts from multiple devices). since cache is modify the value of incorrect attempts while accessing
from multiple device.